# CSS - IE6 overflow

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I can see some other question have been raised around this issue but none of the answers fixed it for me.

I have a table which is inside a `<div>`. In IE7 and above this renders fine and the table can be seen clearly using scroll bars. In IE6 however this renders as a single line (e.g. height of 1px).

Here is the css around these elements.

```
    DIV.ScrollFrame {
        overflow: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .DataTable {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
```

Then the html look like this

```
<div class="ScrollFrame" >
    <table class="DataTable">
        //some asp to generate the data
    </table>
</div>
```

Sorry a cannot provide pictures as the data in the table is confidential.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are even attempting to support IE6?

Comment: I'm only a developer. People above me make those kind of decisions. But at a guess, isn't the customer the boss.

Comment: Microsoft feels your pain: http://ie6countdown.com/index.html

Comment: Yeah you are right but even Microsoft is trying to kill ie6 http://www.ie6countdown.com/ And if your data is confidential blur data :)

Comment: Although your points are valid (and I agree with you), they aren't the answers I'm looking for. for anyone else wanting to comment on the use of IE6, this is want the customer wants.

Comment: Try hardcoding pixel-heights?

Comment: Oh yeah, be sure to itemize the bill "supporting old browser" :)

Comment: @sarnold - Can't believe I didn't try that but that works. Though what could a do about the possibility of different screen resolutions.

Comment: @ash, or worse, someone who has configured their computer to use large fonts due to poor eyesight. You cannot make it look good. :(

Comment: @sarnold: re poor eyesight - the number of people still using IE6 is pretty low now, and I'd have thought the numbers still using IE6 who have accessibility issues must be even smaller; if you've got that kind of issue, you'd surely have upgraded by now. So I'd say it's okay to rig it with a fixed pixel height just for IE6, if you really must support it. And agreed with @sarnold's other common - you definitely need to make sure that the boss understands the financial cost of his decision to support IE6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your solution is to set a fixed height, make sure you serve it for IE6 only. Best practice is to use an IE6 only stylesheet displayed with conditional comments, like so:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
        <link href="/styles/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Alternatively you can use the `* html` hack, which only IE6 understands.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i´m not sure, but you can try this for ie6:

```
* html DIV.ScrollFrame { overflow:scroll; }
```